# Code error with variable storage from selected feature

Tags: python, variables, qgis

I'm using QGIS 3.6 with the built in Python text editor. I have found a snippet of code that I'm trying to make work, and I've modified it to the best of my abilities to fit my specific needs. I have a point layer called "Regulators" and it contains a field called "Town". The idea of the code is that when I select a single feature on the "Regulators" layer, the code will look at the "Town" field, and select all other features that match that field's value. I select a feature, run this code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
field_name = 'Town'

values = []
for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
    tmp_value = feat[field_name]
    if tmp_value not in values:
        values.append(str(tmp_value))

strings = []
for val in values:
    if val != values[-1]:
        string = field_name + ' = ' + val +  ' or '
        strings.append(string)
    else:
        last_string = field_name + ' = ' + val
        strings.append(last_string)
query = ''.join(strings)

request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
request.setSubsetOfAttributes([]).setFilterExpression(query)

selection = layer.getFeatures(request)
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'setSelectedFeatures'
```

I'm very much new to python, and see nothing wrong with line 1 or 5. I have found some other codes that do what I'm attempting here, but they also return errors, so I'm wondering if there is some method or function that has changed since this code was posted. The integrated compiler with QGIS is also much different than I am used to.

EDIT: I've updated the code and the error message based on feedback I've received on the post so far. I assume that QgsVectorLayer is the generic term for a vector layer being referenced, in this case the "Regulators" layer. but I don't understand why it's trying to use the setSelectedFeatures method as an attribute.

Comment: That semicolon needs to be a colon instead.  Also, the next three lines should be indented one level further.

Comment: Okay, I made those changes, and now I get error "File "<input>", line 1, in <module>", and "File "<string>", Line 24 , in <module>"

Comment: That's clearly not the full error message.  It's only the part that tells you *where* the error occurred (and only the "Line 24" part is referring to your code), not the part that tells you what actually went wrong.

Comment: I tried to post what I thought was important. I missed the actual error message somehow. I've updated the post to reflect the new error message. I really appreciate you helping with this.

Comment: `setSelectedFeatures()` was apparently a QGIS 2.x method name.  It's now called `selectByIds()`.  (Source: https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html)

Comment: Okay, so I no replaced setSelectedFeatures with selectByIds and I no longer get the error message. However, it deselects whatever feature I have selected as opposed to selecting all other features that it has essentially filtered. I understand a lot of the code, but I'll be honest some of it I do not understand. I am assuming the last line actually selects the other features based on the selection defined in the line above. Not sure if the problem is in the "selecting" portion or the filtering portion. I have used other compilers that have allowed me to "step-into" the code. That's helpful.